# Spring Boot: Best Practice For Storing Logger Object

Tags: java, spring-boot

What is/are the best practices for using Logger in Spring Boot? Currently I am creating a Logger per file and using that for the debug with a `Logger.getLogger(<the class>.class)`.

I'm not sure if that's the best practice because with every controller I create one, which will add up eventually.

1. Is it not a bad practice to just instantiate a different logger per file?
2. What is/are the best practices for using it?

Comment: Should be a static final variable associated with a class.  There's no benefit or savings in reusing them, in my view.  Create one per controller and sleep at night.  It's the least of your worries.

Comment: You can also look at Lombok `@Slf4j` annotation, https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/logging-with-lombok/  to make your life a little bit easier.

In my years of pratice, never seen any project where Loggers are cached/optimized in anyway.

Comment: I tend to agree with SMA and duffymo. There's no problem in creating a different logger object per class. `@Slf4j` annotation does the same, but without the boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I prefer to use the @Slf4j annotation for logging with Spring boot but here is a nice list of the possibilities:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-logging